# I'm getting invalid app error

Tags: android, uber-api

While trying to authenticate my user i'm getting this error "INVALID_APP_SIGNATURE" i don't think there is something wrong with my code

i have properly added all my app details in uber developer dashboard

I tried using sample given in github page but im getting the same error

Comment: It is the same sample code Uber has provided in github.com

Comment: share github link or put your code.

Comment: https://github.com/uber/rides-android-sdk/blob/master/samples/login-sample/src/main/java/com/uber/sdk/android/samples/LoginSampleActivity.java I have implemented this code with my client ID and request URI

Comment: It is working fine if the app is not installed l...

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're trying to [Login using the SDK](https://github.com/uber/rides-android-sdk#login)? Did you register the hash of your application's signing certificate?

To get the hash of your signing certificate, run this command with the alias of your key and path to your key store:

`keytool -exportcert -alias <your_key_alias> -keystore <your_keystore_path> | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64`

The resulting hash should be added to the Application Signature section in the [Developer Dahsboard](https://developer.uber.com/dashboard).

Can you double check if the piece is correct, please? [The error should include your application signature](https://github.com/uber/rides-android-sdk/blob/master/core-android/src/main/java/com/uber/sdk/android/core/auth/LoginManager.java#L322). You can use that to compare what you entered in the dashboard.

Comment: No I dint get the application signature with the error.... There is no change in the code... Do I have to generate a signed apk to use this?

Comment: In developer dashboard Url. I not able to find application signature.

Answer (score 0):

Alex's solution worked for me. For quick testing (non-production), you can just add your debug key to the Application signature section.

`keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64`

By default the debug keystore has a blank password.

Comment: my key is in the Uber Developers site but I still get the error.